# Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@externalNativeBuild/compileClasspath'

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have written code in CPP and linked with gradle using cmake now there another sub module like bottomsheet and few more and now while sync gradle I get the following error:

**Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@externalNativeBuild/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :bottomsheet**

**build.gradle(Module:app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.devmedia.videostatus"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 4
        versionName "1.3"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        debug {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                // Provides a relative path to your CMake build script
                path "CMakeLists.txt"
            }
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.0.0'

    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.10.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'

    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation project(path: ':bottomsheet')
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

How can resolve above error ?